# Can I display the results of a Select Case in a TextBox in VisualBasic?

Tags: vb.net

I am currently creating a code for a school project. The assignment is to create a pretty basic mark book system for teachers. I am using "Select Case" to determine the Grade the student receives for their percentage on a test.

My current issue is that in this code I have it displaying the output information into a display box but I actually need it placed into a Text box or a Label. When I try to change to either of these forms I get an error.

What can I replace the line lsbResults.Items.Add with so that the information that follows appears in a text box or label?

```
    Public Sub Grades()
    Select Case Percentage
        Case 0 To 49
            lsbResults.Items.Add(StudentName & "'s" & " grade is a participation" & " (" & Percentage & "%)")
        Case 50 To 59
            lsbResults.Items.Add(StudentName & "'s" & " grade is a Pass" & " (" & Percentage & "%)")
        Case 60 To 74
            lsbResults.Items.Add(StudentName & "'s" & " grade is a Credit" & " (" & Percentage & "%)")
        Case 75 To 89
            lsbResults.Items.Add(StudentName & "'s" & " grade is a Distiction" & " (" & Percentage & "%)")
        Case 90 To 100
            lsbResults.Items.Add(StudentName & "'s" & " grade is a High Distinction" & " (" & Percentage & "%)")
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: here is just 1 of many ideas.  Instead of `lsbResults.Items.Add` - you can add to a string variable,  `output &= `  and ultimately, after `End Select` assign the `.Text` property of the Label or TextBox to output.  `outTextbox.Text = output`.  Give that a shot and let us know.

Comment: @Jim thankyou very much for the help, I've added those edits into my code but now when I enter my information into my textbox and it places the result into the specified text box, after it clears and new information is placed into the textbox it repeats the answer from the last input.

Comment: @Laura Please [edit] your question to show the code as it is now.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you are calling `Grades` from another class, it can be a `Private Sub`. I added `Percentage` and `StudentName` as parameters of the `Grades` method to make class level variables unnecessary. If this data is available as class level variables then the parameters are not necessary.

To avoid repeating the code, I only changed one word in the Select Case.

I used an interpolated string indicated by the $ before the quote. This lets you place variables enclosed in braces in a string exactly where they will appear in the final text. I added a `vbCrLf` to the end of the string to start a new line.

The `.AppendText` method will add the new string to the text box without erasing what is already there. Be sure that your text box has `.Multiline` set to true in the designer.

```
Private Sub Grades(Percentage As Integer, StudentName As String)
    Dim GradeWord As String = ""
    Select Case Percentage
        Case 0 To 49
            GradeWord = "participation"
        Case 50 To 59
            GradeWord = "Pass"
        Case 60 To 74
            GradeWord = "Credit"
        Case 75 To 89
            GradeWord = "Distiction"
        Case 90 To 100
            GradeWord = "High Distinction"
        Case Else
            GradeWord = "No Grade"
    End Select
    TextBox1.AppendText($"{StudentName}'s grade is {GradeWord} ({Percentage}%){vbCrLf}")
End Sub
```

I you are using a version of Visual Studio prior to 2015 then you will need to use `String.Format`

```
    TextBox1.AppendText(String.Format("{0}'s grade is {1} ({2}%){3}", StudentName, GradeWord, Percentage, vbCrLf))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the grade in to a variable and later display it in a textbox or label using .text

Public Sub Grades()

Dim strGrade as String

```
Select Case Percentage
    Case 0 To 49
        strGrade = (StudentName & "'s" & " grade is a participation" & " (" & Percentage & "%)")

    Case 50 To 59
        strGrade =  (StudentName & "'s" & " grade is a Pass" & " (" & Percentage & "%)")

    Case 60 To 74
        strGrade = (StudentName & "'s" & " grade is a Credit" & " (" & Percentage & "%)")

    Case 75 To 89
        strGrade =   (StudentName & "'s" & " grade is a Distiction" & " (" & Percentage & "%)")

    Case 90 To 100
        strGrade =  (StudentName & "'s" & " grade is a High Distinction" & " (" & Percentage & "%)")
End Select
```

TxtBoxFinalGrade.text=strGrade

End Sub

Comment: Thankyou for this this code it worked perfectly, I am very greatful

Comment: No problem. Please mark the answer correct and upvote if it helped you